# Linux Command Line: Sort, Grep, Less commands

Tags: linux, command-line

How do I go about doing this:

Using the `sort`, `grep` and `less` commands (connected with a pipe), sort the `/etc/passwd` file in alphabetical order and display only the lines ending in the word "false".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
grep false$ /etc/passwd | sort | less
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this on Mac OS X 10.6, but I feel that it should work on Linux also:

```
sort /etc/passwd | grep '^.*false$' | less
```